# After installing psycopg2, I cannot import it properly

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, psycopg2, importerror, dlopen

When I tried to import psycopg2 with this simple line of code:

```
import psycopg2
```

The following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Someone has an idea of why this happens?

Answer (score 13):

I've had the same issue. After digging a little into the thread provided by @singingstone, the solution that worked for me was to `pip uninstall psycopg2`, then `pip install psycopg2-binary`.

Answer (score -1):

Try `pip install aws-psycopg2` worked for me